# Solaris 10 boot from cd-rom

Tags: boot, solaris

I am trying to start up my solaris server using the newly downloaded iso written on a CD.

The iso name is `sol-10-u9-ga-sparc-dvd.iso`

When we started the server, logging in as root then tried to boot the system from CD-Rom, this is what happened:

```
sc> reset  
Are you sure you want to reset the system (y/n)? y
Chassis | critical: Host has been reset
Performing hard reset on the system

Chassis | critical: Host has been powered off
sc> poweronChassis | major: Host has been powered on

The Host System Power is already running.

sc> Chassis | major: Mar 28 13:47:34 ERROR: MB/CMP0/BR2/CH0/D0 must be populated, MB/CMP0/MCU2 not configured
Chassis | major: Mar 28 13:47:34 ERROR: MB/CMP0/BR3/CH0/D0 must be populated, MB/CMP0/MCU3 not configured

Chassis | major: Mar 28 13:47:34 ERROR: MB/CMP0/L2_BANK4, MB/CMP0/L2_BANK5 unused because MB/CMP0/MCU2 is not configured

Chassis | major: Mar 28 13:47:34 ERROR: MB/CMP0/L2_BANK6, MB/CMP0/L2_BANK7 unused because MB/CMP0/MCU3 is not configured

Chassis | major: Mar 28 13:47:34 ERROR: Degraded configuration: system operating at reduced capacity

Chassis | major: Mar 28 13:47:34 ERROR: System DRAM Available: 016384 MB

Chassis | major: Mar 28 13:47:34 ERROR: Only 4 cores, up to 32 cpus are configured because some L2_BANKS are unusable
```

After this, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> brings us a command prompt for `sc>`, but no boot command is recognized here.

How can we boot from the CD?

Comment: Just to check, you did burn the ISO to a DVD, not a CD, right?  The filename suggests a DVD iso file.  If you're missing a big hunk of the initrd, you might run into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give some more information? 
If that is an Openboot, you can boot from cdrom with:

```
sc> boot cdrom
```

Anyway those `ERROR` messages doesn't look good.

Comment: thx for advices, I figured out the solution with my friend just interrupted the booting and when it asked us for the boot device;
we are running

So the answer solving my problem partially.

>boot cdrom command.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably only on service processor (ALOM/ILOM's `sc>` prompt ). You should type `console -f` to attach the real solaris host.
Then `init 0` and from the OK prompt type `boot cdrom`.

For more information, see [this introductory article](http://www.fatmin.com/2008/04/alom-ilom-elom.html) or [this cheat sheet](http://users.wowway.com/~captainkirk/computers/SolarisILOMALOMCheatSheet.htm).

Comment: thank you very much for this brief. As I stated I have solved my problem.